# Add FactoryGirl factory after initial define

Tags: ruby, testing, activerecord, factory-bot

I'm trying to write a test using FactoryGirl and want to create a factory for a class that gets generated based on an input parameter. So in my `setup` block I tried something like this:

```
setup do
  FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :my_table_1, :class => MyTable.create_subclass(1) do
      my_table_traits
    end
  end
end
```

where `MyTable.create_subclass` returns a subclass of `MyTable` built using the arguments (`MyTable`, as you might guess, is an `ActiveRecord` class).

But this doesn't work. I found that if I added a call to `FactoryGirl.find_definitions`, but this results in duplicate definition errors. I also tried changing `define` to `modify`, but that doesn't seem to be capable of adding a factory, only modifying an existing one.

How can I add a factory when the test runs? Or, better yet, is there an alternative way to set up this factory for a dynamically created class that doesn't even exist until the test runs?

**Context:**

`MyTable` is the final table data will get loaded into. During processing, I create temporary tables to load data into to stage it before it gets loaded into the real table. Those temp tables are represented by subclasses of `MyTable` that are generated dynamically based on an argument. The purpose of this test is to verify we correctly insert data into `MyTable` after we are done staging it in the subclass/temp table.

Since I already use FactoryGirl to create test data for other things, it is a natural extension to want to use it to create test data for the temp tables in this test.

Comment: Why would you want to create new factory definitions during the tests? It kinda defeats the purpose of factories. If you really want to do this, I suggest you use a helper method that ability to create or build instances of different classes...

Comment: I added something about the context of this to explain why I'm trying to do it. I realize it's not a normal use case for factories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A coworker showed me how to do this. You have to override 'initialize_with' and use the special 'attributes' variable to get the job done.

```
factory :my_table_temp_loading_table, :class => ActiveRecord::Base do
  initialize_with do
    MyTable.create_subclass(attributes[:subclass_id]).new(attributes)
  end
  my_table_traits
end
```